# Python code should only output 5 character long words

Tags: python

My code picks a random word from a `file.txt`. I am trying the get the code to pick only 5 character words but I'm not getting the desired output.
If it randomly picks a word and if its not 5 characters long it should move on or ignore it and pick another word. I keep getting words with more that 5 characters. Am I wrong somewhere?

```
words = r"C:\users\Cece\words.txt" 

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(words)]
wordsC = lines
randword = random.choice(wordsC)


while randword == 5:
    if len(randword) == 5:
       word = randword.upper()
       myword =  list(word)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: I have a feeling that `while randword == 5` is not right, and that you don't intend to be evaluating the same word forever...

Comment: you are checking if `randowrd == 5` which will never be `True` as `randword` is a string and 5 is an int. You would want to formulate your loop so that the condition is that the length of the word is **not** 5, and think what you should do in that else part other than `continue`

Comment: Should your while loop be nested in a loop to ensure it gets a different word each time its run?

Comment: Side note: picking a random word out of all and then checking if it's a 5-letter word isn't really...effective. You might be very unlucky and keep on not picking any 5-letter word for a long time. Pick all 5-letter words and then pick a random one out of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your while loop isn't needed and its condition is incorrect, you are comparing a string to a number rather than the strings length.

You can avoid all of this by just filtering the list in the first place

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(words) if len(line.rstrip('\n')) == 5]
```

Comment: The best shortest solution to the problem. You’re star

Answer (score 3):

All you need *to pick only 5 character words*:

```
with open(r"C:\users\Cece\words.txt") as f:
    words_5 = []
    for line in f:
        word = line.strip()
        if len(word) == 5:
            words_5.append(word.upper())
```

Comment: Upvote for pythonic code, *raw string* should be used here as a filepath though.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

```
randword = random.choice(wordsC)
```

Let's assume that  len(randword) at this point is 8 --> *abcabcab*

After that you do the following check:

while randword == 5: <----- this checks if randword is equal to 5 as an integer. False as `"abcabcab" != 5`

**The solution:**

```
randword = random.choice(wordsC)

while len(randword) != 5:
    randword = random.choice(wordsC)
word = randword.upper()
myword =  list(word)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Nice solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Import words into a list first.
Use the `random` library

```
import random
filename = r"C:\users\Cece\words.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
words5 = []
for x in content:
    if len(x) == 5:
        words5.extend(x) 
print(random.choice(words5))
```

Comment: You're using `==` instead of `=` for `filename` assignment, also `filename` should be a raw string `r"C:\users\Cece\words.txt"` or backslashes should be escaped `"C:\\users\\Cece\\words.txt"`.

Comment: Thank you Asikorski for the solution and Tyler for the contribution. Much appreciated. Just a quick note. When I run the solution. It only print out just one character. Just one letter and not a word.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def take_random_5(l):
    randword = random.choice(l)
    if len(randword) != 5:
        return 
    return randword

words = r"C:\users\Cece\words.txt" 
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(words)]
while True:
    take_random_5(lines)
```